# Find isolated points for given this set.

Tags: general-topology

Let the metric space $(\mathbb{C},T)$ whose metric, $d(z,w)$ is defined like the below.(Here $z, w \in \mathbb{C}$)

$d(z,w) =
\begin{cases}
\vert z -w \vert  & \text{$\vert z \vert= \vert w \vert$} \\
\vert z \vert + \vert w \vert & \text{$\vert z \vert \neq \vert w \vert$}
\end{cases}$

Find the $\bar A - A'$ for $A=\{x+yi ; \vert x \vert + \vert y \vert \leq2\}$

---

Considering the First case $z =(0,0)$ with taking adequately small number $\epsilon(>0)$

Then open ball $B(z, \epsilon) = \{w ; \vert w \vert < \epsilon \}$

On the other hand, the case $z \neq (0,0)$ with taking the $\epsilon < \vert z \vert$

Then open ball $B(z, \epsilon) = \{z \}$ (Discrete topological space for $z\neq 0$)

So In my thought $(\mathbb{C},T)$ has opensets like $\{z\}, (z \neq 0)$ or $\{ z ; \vert z \vert\ < \epsilon \}$

Hence at least I thought,  $\bar A - A' = A \setminus (0,0)$

But the answer was $(2,0), (-2,0), (0,2)$ and $(0,-2)$. What the point did I have a mistake?

Any answer always welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're *almost* right in the understanding of the topology: $0 \in \Bbb C$ has its standard neighbourhoods $B(0,\varepsilon)=\{z \in \Bbb C: |z| < \varepsilon\}$, while other points $z$ of $\Bbb C$ have neighbourhoods that are  small arcs of the same radius as $z$ (!). What you describe is the post office metric, where all $d(u,v)=|u|+|v|$, except when $u=v$.

So no point of $A$ is isolated except the extreme points mentioned in your answer: these are isolated, because the circle of radius $2$ intersects $A$ exactly at those points, so small arcs show that $2, 2i, -2, -2i$ are isolated in $A$.

Comment: Henno, this isn't the post office metric. Concentric circles centred around $0 \in \Bbb{C}$ all have the same metric as the usual metric on $\Bbb{C}$, and hence the same subspace topology. The answer given is actually correct.

Comment: @user804886 I saw that later, I corrected.

Comment: Cool answer. :)